# Why does cSplit returns TRUE instead of the character

Tags: r, split

I have this (simplified) dataset:

```
x <- read.table(text  = '  id                                                 seq
1  1 AACCAAGCCCTTGCTCAAATCGAAAAAAAGTTGAGCAAACCGAGTTTTGAG
2  2 AAGTTGAGCAAACCGAGTTTTGAGACTTGGATGAAGTCAACCAAAGCCCAC')
```

Which thus looks like this:

```
  id                                                 seq
1  1 AACCAAGCCCTTGCTCAAATCGAAAAAAAGTTGAGCAAACCGAGTTTTGAG
2  2 AAGTTGAGCAAACCGAGTTTTGAGACTTGGATGAAGTCAACCAAAGCCCAC
```

When I then subject it to cSplit:
`cSplit(x, 'seq', direction = 'wide', stripWhite = FALSE, sep = '')` it returns `TRUE` for positions 20 and 32 instead of the character itself:

```
   id seq_01 seq_02 seq_03 seq_04 seq_05 seq_06 seq_07 seq_08 seq_09 seq_10 seq_11 seq_12 seq_13 seq_14 seq_15 seq_16 seq_17 seq_18
1:  1      A      A      C      C      A      A      G      C      C      C      T      T      G      C      T      C      A      A
2:  2      A      A      G      T      T      G      A      G      C      A      A      A      C      C      G      A      G      T
   seq_19 seq_20 seq_21 seq_22 seq_23 seq_24 seq_25 seq_26 seq_27 seq_28 seq_29 seq_30 seq_31 seq_32 seq_33 seq_34 seq_35 seq_36
1:      A   TRUE      C      G      A      A      A      A      A      A      A      G      T   TRUE      G      A      G      C
2:      T   TRUE      T      G      A      G      A      C      T      T      G      G      A   TRUE      G      A      A      G
   seq_37 seq_38 seq_39 seq_40 seq_41 seq_42 seq_43 seq_44 seq_45 seq_46 seq_47 seq_48 seq_49 seq_50 seq_51
1:      A      A      A      C      C      G      A      G      T      T      T      T      G      A      G
2:      T      C      A      A      C      C      A      A      A      G      C      C      C      A      C
```

(If I instead change `direction = 'wide'` to `direction = 'long'` and than spread it myself using `tidyr::spread` it looks fine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THe issue is with `type.convert` which is `TRUE` by default.  So, if there are only `T` or `F` in a column, it thinks as `TRUE/FALSE` instead of the string "T" or "F" and converts it to `logical` type

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(x, 'seq', direction = 'wide', stripWhite = FALSE,
     sep = '', type.convert = FALSE)
# id seq_01 seq_02 seq_03 seq_04 seq_05 seq_06 seq_07 seq_08 seq_09 seq_10 seq_11 seq_12 seq_13 seq_14 seq_15
#1:  1      A      A      C      C      A      A      G      C      C      C      T      T      G      C      T
#2:  2      A      A      G      T      T      G      A      G      C      A      A      A      C      C      G
#   seq_16 seq_17 seq_18 seq_19 seq_20 seq_21 seq_22 seq_23 seq_24 seq_25 seq_26 seq_27 seq_28 seq_29 seq_30
#1:      C      A      A      A      T      C      G      A      A      A      A      A      A      A      G
#2:      A      G      T      T      T      T      G      A      G      A      C      T      T      G      G
#   seq_31 seq_32 seq_33 seq_34 seq_35 seq_36 seq_37 seq_38 seq_39 seq_40 seq_41 seq_42 seq_43 seq_44 seq_45
#1:      T      T      G      A      G      C      A      A      A      C      C      G      A      G      T
#2:      A      T      G      A      A      G      T      C      A      A      C      C      A      A      A
#   seq_46 seq_47 seq_48 seq_49 seq_50 seq_51
#1:      T      T      T      G      A      G
#2:      G      C      C      C      A      C
```